# Selenium SetUserAgentOverride not retain when click other page

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Selenium SetUserAgentOverride not retain when move page, go new window, or new tab

I know chrome option using "--user-agent", it can retain

But I want also change userAgentData

So I was testing about override useragent, but problem is when page change, its not retain

```
domains.Network.Enable(new Network.EnableCommandSettings());
domains.Network.SetUserAgentOverride(new Network.SetUserAgentOverrideCommandSettings()
{
    UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
});
```

```
session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V94.DevToolsSessionDomains>().Emulation.SetUserAgentOverride(new Emulation.SetUserAgentOverrideCommandSettings()
{
    UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the *`SetUserAgentOverride`* flag you need to set [*Emulation.setUserAgentOverride*](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride)

```
Emulation.setUserAgentOverride: Allows overriding user agent with the given string.

PARAMETERS
    userAgent(string): User agent to use.
    acceptLanguage(string): Browser langugage to emulate.
    platform(string): The platform navigator.platform should return.
```

However, as `@whimboo` mentions in ["Emulation.setUserAgentOverride" should only affect the current target](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1596136) with the availability of [Implement Emulation.setUserAgentOverride](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1595697) **`Emulation.setUserAgentOverride`** implementation currently doesn't only affect the active session, but Firefox globally.